# How to redirect to a url when using modal forms in django

Tags: django, bootstrap-modal, redirect

Having a model (ProductSerialNumbers) which simulates a product with a serial number and after a successful implementation of the CRUD cycle with the aid of modal fm forms https://github.com/django-fm/django-fm

i face up the problem of unsuccessful redirection to other url after a successful delete of the object. The app keeps showing the modal fm window after clicking ok(for delete).

How can i solve that to redirect to my list of ProductSerialNumbers?

Here is my code of the view and a part of my template concerning the modal-delete.

**view**

```
class ProductSerialNumbersDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, AjaxDeleteView):
    model = ProductSerialNumbers
    success_url = reverse_lazy('warehouse_stuffing')

    '''Function for deleting only the ProductSerialNuumbers which belong to an order, otherwise can not delete '''
    # Patch queryset to get the productSerialNumber
    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        if (self.object.order):
            print("It belongs to an order, do not delete")
            return redirect('/warehouse_stuffing/')
        else:
            print("It is not in an order,delete")
            self.object.delete()
            print(self.success_url)
            return redirect('/warehouse_stuffing/')
```

seems that the redirect() function is not working properly.

**template**

```
 <td><a href="{% url 'warehouse_stuffing_delete' products_with_serial_numbers.id %}" class="fm-delete" data-fm-head="Delete of entry {{ products_with_serial_numbers }};" data-fm-callback="reload" ><button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" type="">Delete</button></a></td>
```

Comment: The view is called by ajax, so the redirect is returned to and processed by javascript, which obviously won't result in a redirect of the page. If you want to redirect, you should set `data-fm-callback` to `redirect_from_response` or `redirect`, as described in the [documentation](https://github.com/django-fm/django-fm) and change your view to send the redirect url in the response (or since it's static just hardcode it in your `data-fm-target` attribute).

Answer (score 1):

The view is called by ajax, so the redirect is returned to and processed by javascript, which obviously won't result in a redirect of the page.

If you want to redirect, you should:

- set `data-fm-callback` to `redirect_from_response` or `redirect`, as described in the [documentation](https://github.com/django-fm/django-fm)
- and change your view to send the redirect url in the response (or since it's static just hardcode it in your `data-fm-target` attribute and the view returns just the status 'ok': `self.render_json_response(self.get_success_result())`).

Comment: useful notice about the Ajax dependency. However, it does not solve my problem changing the delete modal to :                 <td><a href="{% url 'warehouse_stuffing_delete' products_with_serial_numbers.id %}" class="fm-delete" data-fm-head="Delete Entry {{ products_with_serial_numbers }};" data-fm-callback="redirect" data-fm-target="{% url 'warehouse_stuffing'%}" ><button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" type="">Delete</button></a></td>

Comment: Why not? What happens after you made the change? And remember to change your view back to return the default for the AjaxDeleteView (use `super()`). It should return a 200 response not a redirect.

Comment: The app responds as before, Delete happens but redirect not. i tried this : class ProductSerialNumbersDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, AjaxDeleteView):
    model = ProductSerialNumbers
    success_url = reverse_lazy('warehouse_stuffing')

  
    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        if (self.object.order):
            return super(ProductSerialNumbersDeleteView,self)
        else:
            self.object.delete()
            return super(ProductSerialNumbersDeleteView,self)

Comment: It's hard to read code in the comments, but if you just return `super()` you're returning the class itself, which is still not the 200 response with JSON body. You should just return `self.render_json_response(self.get_success_result())`. The ajax script is likely to never execute the code it's supposed to execute on success if you don't return the correct response. Check in your browser's developer tools to see what the response is, it should just be the JSON "{"status": "ok"}"

Comment: my return is : return self.render_json_response(self.get_success_result()). The data target is  data-fm-target="{% url 'warehouse_stuffing' %}" ....it seems to redirect but it can not found the redirection endpoint. It gives a 404 error redirecting to path /warehouse_stuffing/undefined

Comment: strange that it's adding `/undefined` after the url you specify. Maybe check the javascript itself with a breakpoint to see why this is happening.

Comment: finally I found the solution. The key was to put data-fm-callback="redirect" data-fm-target="{% url 'url_name' %}"

Answer (score 0):

Finally after searching I came out with this solution:

view.py

```
class ProductSerialNumbersDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, AjaxDeleteView):
    model = ProductSerialNumbers
    success_url = reverse_lazy('warehouse_stuffing')

    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        if (self.object.order):
            return self.render_json_response(self.get_success_result())

        else:
            self.object.delete()
            return self.render_json_response(self.get_success_result())
```

and in my template as far as the fm-delete is concerned the structure is:

```
<td><a href="{% url 'warehouse_stuffing_delete' products_with_serial_numbers.id %}" class="fm-delete" data-fm-head="Delete of entry {{ products_with_serial_numbers }};" data-fm-callback="redirect" data-fm-target="{% url 'warehouse_stuffing' %}"><button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" type="">Delete</button></a></td>
```

in summary the return must be:

```
return self.render_json_response(self.get_success_result())
```

and the modal delete must be:

```
data-fm-callback="redirect" data-fm-target="{% url 'url_name' %}"
```